# Array keys match PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to write a PHPUnit test which asserts that the array I am testing has the correct keys.

```
$structure = ['title', 'message', 'action'];
$structure = array_flip($structure);
$result = array_diff_key($structure, $response);

$this->assertEquals($result, []);
```

This test works, but there must be a cleaner way to do this with PHPUnit 4.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an asserting for each key:

```
$this->assertArrayHasKey('key', $response);  
$this->assertArrayHasKey('message', $response); 
$this->assertArrayHasKey('action', $response);
```

Hope this help